# Is it possible to view the tax rates of a settlement besides when you first enter the settlement?

Tags: new-world

When you first enter a settlement, the tax rates briefly display on the screen.  However, this is the only way I've been able to view them.

I once entered a settlement where the tax rates were a very high 20% for each of the taxable settlement features.  If I knew this ahead of time, I would have travelled to a different town with lower rates to perform my crafting, but I have not found a way to view the tax rates from the world map, or any other way.

Can you view the tax rates of a settlement aside from when they display upon entering a settlement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your map, default <kbd>M</kbd>, and click on the settlement icon for the place you are curious about. Taxes along with town upgrade information, influence, and your storage are all available as info to you on the right side of the screen where it will pop up a tab.

See the tax info on the bottom right next to town upgrades. From top to bottom it is 'Property Tax' 'Trading Tax' 'Crafting Fee' 'Refining Fee'

[image]

Comment: Ok, so I was blind.  I totally passed over those tax rates in the bottom thinking they were just additional "Tier X" info for the various crafting stations.

Comment: Yeah it's a lot of info - tax info seems to stay accurate, but the station upgrades are occasionally bugged still, e.g you may go to the town and have the upgrade actually be a tier higher than the map indicated.